# compare time difference between current time with last data timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a data server recording data every second. i need to setup a cron job that that runs a script that can give a reply if the `now()` is 24 hours more than the last data recorded.

So that I can link this to a email alert for recording failure. CAn someone help me? I am new to PostgreSQL and linux, too.

My table provides data as

```
 sensorid |           t         | unscaled_val | scaled_val 
----------+---------------------+--------------+------------- 
       46 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 | 0.008975     | 345.386645 
       32 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 | 0.01202      | 1503.755853 
       45 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 | 0.004        | 50.019719 
       31 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 | 0.013687     | 60.541131 
       18 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 | 0.012655     | 57.372001 
       34 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 | 0.004025     | 4.671827 
       37 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 | 0.004147     | 4.604936
```

Comment: You will need to show your table definitions and some sample data if you want help writing a command.

Comment: My table provides data as  sensorid |          t          | unscaled_val | scaled_val
----------+---------------------+--------------+-------------
       46 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 |     0.008975 |  345.386645
       32 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 |      0.01202 | 1503.755853
       45 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 |        0.004 |   50.019719
       31 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 |     0.013687 |   60.541131
       18 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 |     0.012655 |   57.372001
       34 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 |     0.004025 |    4.671827
       37 | 2014-06-06 11:52:47 |     0.004147 |    4.604936